# How to set content-disposition to 'inline' on GatsbyJS (to display a pdf in browser rather than download it)

Tags: pdf, gatsby, netlify, content-disposition

I've made a website with GatsbyJS and I've got a link to a pdf which I'd rather was opened in browser rather than be downloaded.

I've tried making a _headers file in the public folder (hacky, I know) and I've tried gatsby-plugin-netlify to set headers in gatsby-config.js, but I'm not sure how exactly to code it. The last three lines of the code below is of course wrong.

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
      options: {
        headers: {}, // option to add more headers. `Link` headers are transformed by the below criteria
        allPageHeaders: [], // option to add headers for all pages. `Link` headers are transformed by the below criteria
        mergeSecurityHeaders: true, // boolean to turn off the default security headers
        mergeLinkHeaders: true, // boolean to turn off the default gatsby js headers
        mergeCachingHeaders: true, // boolean to turn off the default caching headers
        transformHeaders: (headers, path) => headers, // optional transform for manipulating headers under each path (e.g.sorting), etc.
        generateMatchPathRewrites: true, // boolean to turn off automatic creation of redirect rules for client only paths
        Content-Disposition: inline
        Content-Disposition: attachment
        Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="melbournewalks.pdf"
      },
    },
  ],
```